# Contribution of the metric tensor towards the Riemann curvature tensor

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature

If I specify a metric tensor in terms of a choice of bases in the co-tangent space at a given point in a manifold, how much information does the metric tell me about the curvature tensor at that point? Can I calculate the curvature tensor entirely from the metric tensor?

Comment: At a single point? None at all. You need to know the metric in the "second order infinitesimal neighborhood" of a given point $x$ to be able to tell the curvature at $x$.

Comment: Or to put Uldreth's comment in different words, you need to know not just the metric but its second derivatives at that point.

Comment: I can still specify it as $g _{\mu\nu} (x)$ at a point in the manifold. The explicit $x$ dependence should contain information about the second order derivatives.

Comment: @IanDsouza: If you're specifying it as a function of x, then you're not specifying it at a point, you're specifying it at all points.

Comment: @BenCrowell I guess expressing $g\mu\nu(x)$ might make sense at given point if you're considering infinitesimal neighborhoods (as you pointed out the second derivative might be important here). I'm a little weary of using the same function $g\mu\nu(x)$ over the entire manifold because $g\mu\nu(x)$ belongs to the (0,2) tensor space defined at some point, say $p_1$. At any other point, wouldn't you have to define a separate  (0,2) tensor space at say point $p_2$ which won't be the same tensor space defined at $p_1$ though there might pull back maps that might take you from one space to the other

Comment: In any case, say I were to have a description of $g_{\mu\nu}(x)$, either over the entire manifold as 1 function or multiple functions at each point's (o,2) tensor space. How would I go about calculating the Riemann curvature tensor? If the procedure is lengthy and is difficult to write out, any link would also be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but you need to know the metric up to the second derivative, so the metric in a neighb. of the manifold. You can do that for the Levi-Civita connection, since it is completely defined by the metric $g$.

Answer (score 0):

Of course.  Given the components of the metric tensor $ g_ {ij} $ you can calculate the Christoffel symbols
$$\Gamma^i_{kl}=\frac{1}{2}g^{im} \left(\frac{\partial g_{mk}}{\partial x^l} + \frac{\partial g_{ml}}{\partial x^k} - \frac{\partial g_{kl}}{\partial x^m} \right)=\frac{1}{2}g^{im} \frac{\partial g_{mk}}{\partial x^l} + \frac{1}{2}g^{im} \frac{\partial g_{ml}}{\partial x^k} - \frac{1}{2}g^{im} \frac{\partial g_{kl}}{\partial x^m},$$
 then you can calculate the components of the curvature tensor $ R_ {ijkl} $
$$R_{iklm}=\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\partial^2g_{im}}{\partial x^k \partial x^l}  + \frac{\partial^2g_{kl}}{\partial x^i \partial x^m} - \frac{\partial^2g_{il}}{\partial x^k \partial x^m} - \frac{\partial^2g_{km}}{\partial x^i \partial x^l} \right) +g_{np} \left( \Gamma^n_{kl} \Gamma^p_{im} -  \Gamma^n_{km} \Gamma^p_{il} \right).$$
 It is a very long procedure, but it is possible.n